# Information from local DB and external source in one view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii

**Situation:**
The simplified situation is this: consider a blog that is build as an MVC project. The YII blog-example is fine for this, but the question is not framework specific: It is nothing special; you have a table with posts and a page build from:

- a model (YII will give you a basic active-record setup)
- a controller that for instance builds the index (list of all posts)
- a view (or some views) that build the actual HTML in the end.

Now I have a working blog, but I also have an external source of information that I want to introduce to this same page: for example an RSS feed.

How do I add this new datasource?

**Possible sollutions**
To clarify what I am struggling with, here are some things I am considering

- Make a new model that gets its information from both sources

  - Feels like the way of least resistance/work
  - It would need to sort the blogposts and RSS items by date
  - It might need to give some sort of flag about what kind of item it is (An RSS item might not have an author, but it does have a source).
  - The fact that above flag feels neccessairy makes me believe these should be 2 models.
- Make a new model for the RSS and make a controller that combines the two sources and feeds it to a view that can handle both types of post
- Something more complicated (maybe more framework specific), but the current view of a post is just one view for one post, and it gets repeated. Instead of one view that handles both types you might want not only a model, but also a view for your RSS, and a controller(?) that does all the mixing and matching?

**Framework notes:**
I'm using YII, but it's not really about YII. Ofcourse if something complicated is to be done I will have to implement it in YII, but it's about the design and the MVC pattern, not about where to put the `;` ;D

Comment: I'm not really sure why the `mvc` tag was edited out and the `rss` tag was edited in. The question is about how to design something with multiple sources in an MVC patterned project, and the rss example was just that: an example.

Answer (score 0):

If i had to do it, i would make a new controller for the view, and use two models.

- I am very new to the mvc pattern, however from what i have gathered till now, it feels like any model should limit itself to only one **data source**. Also in addition to the CRUD operations, the "business logic" (if any) , should be included within that model. Business logic here would mean logic that applies to the data source pertaining to the web app, i.e the things that you have mentioned, like sorting RSS by date.
- Create a controller that accesses these two models, to populate your view(s).
- Finally the best way to organize these components/modules/parts of the mvc, with respect to Yii, depends on your app requirements, and ux.

Now, i think you should put this question in the [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site also.
Hope this helps!
Edit: Not too sure where to put the sorting, controller or view.

Comment: You can argue about what a datasource is. If It is the same actual content (simple example: persons with a name and an email adress) you would want to work with one model in your code that works on this data, apart from where the data comes from? If the data is actual differently in use, you want seperate models, but if they are arguably the same you might not want it. The sorting is about sorting the both sources into 1 list. So if you state you want 2 models, you can by definition not do this sorting in the model.

Comment: Hmm, i think i understand what you are trying to get at. So i think we have to think about how the two datasources are related, and this relation will be fully dependent on the goals of the app, right. The sorting was just an example, i didn't know you wanted to sort the rss and blog into a single list.

Comment: Now i think sorting is only ui so need not be part of model anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

u can hve something like this (I too use yii so the following code follows yii framework)

```
class XyzController extends CController
{
.
.
.
    public function actionAbc()
    {
        .
                .
                .
        $this->render('viewname',array(
            'model1'=>$model1,//for posts frm table
                        'model2'=>$model2 //for rss feed

        ));
    }
}
```

for better understanding try to render two separate views for each type of post inside the parent view "viewname"

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Any ideas on how to go about sorting in the view?

Comment: do u want to sort both the source in to single list?

Comment: Yes, that would be the object in the end

Comment: as both model's data r in the form of array u can merge & sort(or there may b something like merging two model).. bt u knw in whatevr way u do u cannot use yii's pagination class & evn if u write something on ur own u need to first get all the data from two different source(as they r independent of each othr) so the actual use of pagination will b lost i.e. to fetch data in slots in order to reduce execution time. Its a bummer that one model can use one source only.What u say?

Comment: @Pooja hey, i'm new to Yii. Can't you fetch the data according to the sort criteria? And then feed the retrieved data into the pagination array?

Comment: thats completely possible for data frm one model.. how u do sorting on data combined from two model. & Im new to yii too

Comment: @Pooja Say date is the sort criteria, can we do this: 1. Sql sort and fetch according to date from db model. 2. fetch from rss according to date. 3. compare the dates. 4. feed the data to pagination array. Won't this work? with a simple CListView? I need to read about CListView i guess :)

Comment: sorting 1 & 2 doesnt make sense.. wats the use of sorting whn u dont hve the whole data(db+feed).. because sorting needds to b done on the combined data(db+feed). Fetch the data from db,fetch from rss(no sorting here,y work double).. thn sort & feed thm to pagination array. but thn also it wud b really a problm if u hve huge data

Comment: @Pooja I just read a little about CActiveDataProvider. sorting 1,2 is required coz they are seperate, what if there is a record from db in the first fetch, that comes after two fetches of rss? I dont think you'd be convinced with this. But i'm not sure of your suggestion either.

Comment: I'm getting the feeling I'm starting to get behind on the discussion in my own question :) (actually, that's pretty nice). I'd love an example of the pagination thoughts. THe problem with sorting and pagination is that you don't know where all your data is. If you get the data sorted from the 2 models, you can fetch the first X entities. If you sort later you always have to retrieve everything. So if you can "sort" during retrieve, you'll be quicker off if you're just showing the first 10 results (worst case needing to fetch 10 from both models)